# Как правильно поворачивать башню танка за камерой?

Tags: unity3d, rotation

подскажите пожалуйста, как сделать чтобы башня вращалась за камерой по Y с определенной скоростью. Этот код работает, но когда угол камеры меняется с отрицательного на положительный или наоборот, то башня делает полный оборот, как это исправить?

```
 if (transform.eulerAngles.y > _cameraOffset.eulerAngles.y)
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.down * _rotationAnglePerSecond * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
    else
    {
        transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * _rotationAnglePerSecond * Time.fixedDeltaTime);
    }
```

[Video](https://youtu.be/qyz7nV3_E_I)

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! переведите, пожалуйста, текст вопроса (нажав [edit] ниже текста вопроса) на русский язык

Comment: [Mathf.DeltaAngle](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Mathf.DeltaAngle.html)

Comment: @Yaroslav как его в данном контексте использовать?